# Открытие активити из Service

Tags: android, activity, service

Есть сервис, работающий постоянно, который отслеживает включен ли экран телефона. Как сделать, чтобы при включенном экране сервис открывал активити?

Comment: Тоесть сначала приложение, а потом его активити? А как Вы уже пробовали это сделать? Покажите код. И что именно не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам это? Не занимайтесь глупостью. Во первых это не нормальное поведение приложения, когда при разблокировке он будет тыкать ваше ативити: это поведение вирусняков вымогателей, если ваше приложение не Launcher. Ещё исключением является подмена экранов блокировки, но это тоже зачастую не правильная практика, лучшим вариантов является вывод своей информации на экране блокировки или в виджетах здесь же. Вроде как с 21 АПИ поддерживается.

А во вторых с сервисами сейчас плохая практика. Более надёжным будет использование системное события BroadcastReceivers. Да и сам гугл рекомендует так делать:

```
public class ScreenBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(P.TAG, "ScreenService onReceive");

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        //ваш действия при включении экрана
    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
        //и отключение экрана
    }
}
```

Не забудьте установить его, например в onCreate:

```
screenBroadcastReceiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(screenBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Но для начала стоит с ними ознакомится, например здесь[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/broadcast.php) и [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за идею) никак не мог подобраться, только во втором коде по-другому объявляется:
BroadcastRecivier screenBroadcastReceiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
И приложение не вирусняк, а что-то типо напоминалки, ахахах)
Спасибо еще раз!